# How to make script take STDIN from file and/or other script

Tags: stdin

How do I send STDIN into a script?

script1.ps1 < file.txt

script1.ps1:

```
if(input from file.txt = "string1")
{
//do code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the $input environment variable, this variable stores the piped input, then in your script you can use it to do your code.